# DataGridview, disable Ctrl+Click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` as such:

```
With DataGridView1
   .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
   .ReadOnly = True
   .AllowUserToAddRows = True
   .MultiSelect = False
   .EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
End With
```

When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on last row my `datagridview` lost wanted functionality.
Sometimes select a row sometimes deselect and those little black triangle always jumps one row to lower.
I think this may be built in functionality for adding new data to grid.

Since I need my own <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on last row is there any chance to turn off those built in functionality so last row can behave as any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you mean with a special functionality when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Clicking on a cell. But if what you want is a code being triggered when a cell is clicked and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed, you can rely on the `CellMouseClick` event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    If (Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control) Then
        MessageBox.Show("CTRL & Click")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi varocarbas, this is not a problem. Problem is that if I do Ctrl+Click on last row those black triangle in row header jumps automatically to previous row. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @user973238 as said, I am not sure about what you mean: I have done it myself and nothing happens. Please, explain me the exact conditions (VS version you are using, properties of the DataGridView, etc. or, at least, a snapshot of the problem) and I can try to come up with something either to avoid it or to "over-write" it by relying on the proposed code.

Comment: You are right. Empty project behaves different. I will try to make minimal example to replicate a problem then post it in question...

Comment: I have to apologize since I showed a problem wrongly. This is a part of my bigger project and by isolating it I see that this part work as expected so problem is probably somewhere else. Sorry.

Comment: @user973238 no problem. Thanks for the award though.